# Why Set<Integer> sometimes prints sorted values and sometimes does not?

Tags: java, sorting, set

I have a simple program that prints unique values from a specific range.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Zad3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numbers(5));
    }

    private static Set<Integer> numbers(int howMany) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Set<Integer> numb = new HashSet<>();
        while (numb.size() < howMany) {
            numb.add(rand.nextInt(5) + 1);
        }
        return numb;
    }
}
```

When I set rand to 1-5 it prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] but when I set rand to 1-100 then the outcome is not sorted - ie. [53, 86, 39, 91, 60]. Why is it sorted in 1st example and not in 2nd?

Comment: `HashSet` does not have a guaranteed iteration order. So its elements could be printed in _any_ order.

Comment: A broken clock is also right twice a day

Comment: I don't need it to be ordered. I ran it like 100 times and it is always 1,2,3,4,5 - pretty wierd so I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Set is not ordered. So sometimes it might be, sometimes it might not.

If you want order, you must use some List<> or Treemap<> stuff for instance.

Comment: You probably meant TreeSet

Comment: It depends what you want, Treemap is ordered by key. TreeSet is working too :) You might also use specific Comparator for your need.

Comment: Yes I know Set is not ordered, I don't need it to be ordered but why it is always like 1,2,3,4,5? No reason at all, just a coincidence?

Comment: @wojciechw: follow the links on top of your question, this has been asked and answered in quite some detail before.

Comment: It's a thing from the javacompiler and the hashcode representation of small number. As @JoachimSauer said, check out the link :)